# Save state of GUI with imported images stored in QLabel in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlabel, qsettings

With my application that I am developing with C++ and QT, I am trying to save the state of the GUI with images and widgets imported by the user, so that when the user exits and the application starts again, it's exactly where the user left off with the images and widgets stored exactly in the same place the user placed it.

The images are stored in the QLabels. I've been trying to use the QSettings example code I've seen but it's not working at all. Any ideas of how to save the entire GUI state with the user being able to directly import widgets and images. Cheers :)

Here's my source code of what I've developed so far

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // Load state of GUI
    read_settings();
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Set up the window size
    this->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Raspberry PI GUI v1.0"));
    this->resize(800, 400);

    //-------------------------------------------
    // Setting up buttons on the main screen
    //-------------------------------------------
    // Add label
    button = new QPushButton("Add Graphic", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 20), QSize(200, 50)));
    button->show();

    // Add LED
    button = new QPushButton("Add LCD", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 80), QSize(200, 50)));
    button->show();
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::input_led);

    // Add Next Window
    button = new QPushButton("New Window", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 140), QSize(200, 50)));
    button->show();
    //QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(input_newwindow()));
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::input_newwindow);

    // Add plot
    button = new QPushButton("Add Plot", this);
    button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 200), QSize(200, 50)));
    button->show();
    QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::input_plot);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::close_event(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    write_settings();
    event->accept();
}

void MainWindow::write_settings()
{
    QSettings settings("reaffer Soft", "reafferApp");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    settings.setValue("size", size());
    settings.setValue("pos", pos());
    settings.endGroup();
}

void MainWindow::read_settings()
{
    QSettings settings("reaffer Soft", "reafferApp");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    resize(settings.value("size", QSize(800, 400)).toSize());
    move(settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200)).toPoint());
    settings.endGroup();
}


void MainWindow::input_label()
{
    Label *label = new Label(this);
    label->setText("New Graphic");
    label->show();
}

void MainWindow::input_led()
{
    LED *led = new LED(this);
    led->show();
}

void MainWindow::input_newwindow()
{
    this->hide();
    QMainWindow *newwindow = new QMainWindow();
    newwindow->resize(800, 400);
    newwindow->show();


    // Need to set up and get working correctly
    // Back button
    QPushButton *back_button = new QPushButton(newwindow);
    back_button->setText("Back");
    back_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 80), QSize(200, 50)));
    back_button->show();
    QObject::connect(back_button, &QPushButton::pressed, newwindow, &QMainWindow::hide);
    // Need to go back to previous screen
    this->show();


    // Forward button
    QPushButton *forward_button = new QPushButton(newwindow);
    forward_button->setText("Next");
    forward_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(50, 140), QSize(200, 50)));
    forward_button->show();
    // Create a new screen
    QObject::connect(forward_button, &QPushButton::pressed, this, &QMainWindow::show);
    this->hide();

}

void MainWindow::input_plot()
{
    QMainWindow *windowplot = new QMainWindow();
    windowplot->resize(800, 400);
    windowplot->show();
}

void MainWindow::ButtonClicked()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you actually save the state of your custom widgets? I only see that you save und load the position and size of the main window itself, not its children!? Btw you can save the basic position and size with [QWidget::saveGeometry()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) and load it with [QWidget::restoreGeometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry) and the state of the toolbar and dock widgets from `QMainWindow` with [QMainWindow::saveState](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#saveState) and load it with [QMainWindow::restoreState](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#restoreState) respectively.

If you want to save the position and image path of your custom labels, just use a similar approach like this:

```
QSettings settings("MyCompany", "MyApp");
settings.beginGroup("label1"); // your widget id
settings.setValue("geometry", label1->saveGeometry());
settings.setValue("imagePath", label1->text()); // or wherever you save the image
settings.endGroup();
```

That is a least my simple idea on how to solve your problem, for more details your need to provide more infos.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I understand that I was only trying to load the position and size of the main window itself and not save it's children's position.

I'm still stuck on the part of saving the position of saving the position and image path of the custom labels using the read/write QSettings code. I think I've got the write settings code right but not the read settings.

```
void MainWindow::write_settings()
{
    QSettings settings("reaffer Soft", "reafferApp");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    settings.setValue("size", size());
    settings.setValue("pos", pos());
    settings.setValue("label", label->saveGeometry());  // Save label size
    settings.setValue("imagePath" label->size());   // Save the image loaded 
    settings.endGroup();

    qDebug() << "Write Settings";

}
```

For importing the images to the labels, I'm using a different cpp file. The code for that is shown below.

**Label.cpp**

```
#include "label.h"


//---------------------------------------
// Deconstructor
//---------------------------------------
Label::~Label()
{

}


void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // Move the coordinates on the main window
    m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate = event->x();
    m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate = event->y();
}

void Label::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Allow the user to drag the graphics on the Display
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    move(event->globalX()-m_nMouseClick_X_Coordinate-m_pParentWidget->geometry().x(),

        event->globalY()-m_nMouseClick_Y_Coordinate-m_pParentWidget->geometry().y());
}

void Label::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    //--------------------------------
    // Open file dialog
    //--------------------------------
    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images(*.png, *.dxf, *.jpg"));
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
        tr("Open Images"),
        "/home",
        tr("Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)"));

    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        QImage image(fileName);
        Label::setPixmap(fileName);
        Label::adjustSize();
    }
}
```

Comment: First what you should do is save the path to your image file somewhere in your label, if you don't want to save the whole pixmap to the settings (not recommended). what is this `Label::setPixmap(fileName);`, looks like a static method in your `Label` class? anyway extract the method for loading teh image into your Label so you can reuse it when you load the settings and when you double click it to load it the first time.